# Navigation stack needs at least one root page

Tags: ionic2, navigation

When I call `this.navCtrl.popAll();`, I get this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page

But the root page is set in `app.component.ts`:

```
rootPage = LandingPage;
```

What is still missing?

Comment: What happens when you say `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LandingPage); //popAll` or reverse like `//popall //setRootLandingpage`

Comment: This is the answer to my question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same issue

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page
```

... when I use `registerbackbutton` for hardware back button in Android. And then I try to call `this.navCtrl.pop()` for back to previous page.

My solution:

In app.component.ts

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app';

/* define in constructor */
constructor(public platform: Platform, app: App){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            app.navPop();
        });
    })       
}
```